# Javascript, sorting numbers in particular oreder

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make table that consist of columns and rows. User type how many rows and columns want and on button click and table is created. My problem is to get numbers sorteed in circular way, lowest in bottom right corner and highest in the middle?

This is what i created so far

```js
$('.submit').click(function() {

  var numVal = $('.num').val();
  var otherVal = $('.num2').val();
  var sum = eval(numVal * otherVal);
  var numbers = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= sum; i++) {
    numbers.push(i)
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    $('ul').prepend('<li>' + numbers[i] + '</li>')
  }

  var containerWidth = $('.container').width(numVal * 46 + 'px')
  $('.container').height(otherVal * 46 + 'px')
  $('.wrapper').width(containerWidth + 250 + 'px')
  var middle = numbers[Math.round(($('li').length - 1) / 2)];
});

$('.clear').click(function() {
  $('ul').html('');
  $('.num, .num2').val('').focus();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 230px;
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
ul {} ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="num" />
<input type="text" class="num2" />
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Make Table" />
<input type="button" class="clear" value="clear" />
<div class="container">
  <ul>

  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to look like this

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `sum = eval(numVal * otherVal)` instead of just `sum = numVal * otherVal`?

Comment: Good question haha.

Comment: Use a 2-dimensional array that you fill in the order that you want.

Comment: I am new to javascript but i think that for this it needs to be used some algoritam or somthing like that?

Comment: It will be a somewhat complicated set of `for` loops It will need to keep changing directions, forward versus backwards, and whether it's incrementing x or y.. I think it would be best for your education if you tried to figure it out yourself.

Comment: It's not really specific to Javascript, it would be pretty much the same algorithm in any language. Solving problems like this is the essence of programming. Getting someone else to do it for you is the essence of copying.